# Removing Duplicates from 3 different columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that is structured like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| V8JL504 |  | ADA |
| V8JL504 | 44158 | ADA |

I am trying to remove rows that are exact duplicates (matches in column 1, 2 and 3) of other rows. I have the VBA code below, but it seems to remove the second line of the code every time I run it. Is the RemoveDuplicates function able to do this?

```
CurrentLastRow = currentwb.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(currentwb.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = currentwb.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(currentwb.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(1, 1), currentwb.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(CurrentLastRow, 3))
        Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 3), Header:=xlNo
        wb.Close
```

Comment: `Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score -1):

See the following link:http://sam308.com/search/node/duplicates

Delete Rows Based on Duplicates

Remove Duplicates Macro for Excel 2007

Answer (score -1):

```
'Remove Duplicates Macro
'If you have header then use Header:=xlYes
CurrentLastRow = currentwb.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(currentwb.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = currentwb.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(currentwb.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(1, 1), currentwb.Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(CurrentLastRow, 3))
Rng.Select
Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
Range("A1").Select
```